# How to restrict users from creating SVN branch

Tags: svn

We have seen that the users are creating multiple branches from trunk/branches just by using `svn copy` command.

Is there a way/pre-committ script which will restrict the users from creating branch using `SVN copy` command?

Comment: "Single trunk" workflow isn't brilliant idea. Short-term branches cost almost nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove write access from `branches` folder and can give r/w access to the existing branches like the following:

```
[my_repos:/branches]   
@dev_group = r
@admin = rw

[my_repos:/branches/Release_1.0]  
@dev_group = rw
@admin = rw

[my_repos:/branches/Release_2.0]
@dev_group = rw
@admin = rw
```

Answer (score 1):

Branches are created using the [`svn copy`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create) command. So if your users have write permissions, then they would be able to create branches. And if you want to restrict them then take the write permission